# Kafka jdbc sink connector creates data types that do not matching the original

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I am using Kafka and Kafka Connect to replicate MS SQL Server database to MySQL using debezium sql server CDC source connector and confluent JDBC sink connector. The "auto.create" is set to true and the sink connector did create the tables, but some of the data types do not match. In SQL Sever, I have

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id INTEGER IDENTITY(1001,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  start_date DATE,
  salary INT,
  secret FLOAT,
  create_time TIME
);
```

but in MySQL, it created the following:

```
mysql> desc employees;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| first_name  | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name   | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email       | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| start_date  | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salary      | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| secret      | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| create_time | bigint      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| messageTS   | datetime(3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

ignore messgeTS, that's an extra field I added in the SMT.

The data types for first_name, last_name, email, start_date and create time all do not match. It
converts VARCHAR(255) to text, DATE to int, and TIME to bigint.

Just wondering if anything is misconfigured?

I'm running SQL Server 2019 and MySQL 9.0.28 using docker.

I've also tried the suggestion of disabling autocreate and autoevolve and pre-create the tables with the proper data types.

```
mysql> desc employees;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| start_date  | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| salary      | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| secret      | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| create_time | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| messageTS   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

But it gives the following exceptions when trying to insert into the database:

```
kafka-connect  | [2022-03-04 19:55:07,331] INFO Setting metadata for table "employees" to Table{name='"employees"', type=TABLE columns=[Column{'first_name', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false, sqlType=VARCHAR}, Column{'secret', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false, sqlType=DOUBLE}, Column{'salary', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false, sqlType=INT}, Column{'start_date', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false, sqlType=DATE}, Column{'email', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false, sqlType=VARCHAR}, Column{'id', isPrimaryKey=true, allowsNull=false, sqlType=INT}, Column{'last_name', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false, sqlType=VARCHAR}, Column{'messageTS', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false, sqlType=DATETIME}, Column{'create_time', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false, sqlType=DATETIME}]} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.TableDefinitions)
kafka-connect  | [2022-03-04 19:55:07,382] WARN Write of 4 records failed, remainingRetries=0 (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask)
kafka-connect  | java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '19055' for column 'start_date' at row 1
```

The value of the message is

```
{"id":1002,"first_name":"George","last_name":"Bailey","email":"george.bailey@acme.com","start_date":{"int":19055},"salary":{"int":100000},"secret":{"double":0.867153569942739},"create_time":{"long":1646421476477}}
```

The schema of the message for the start_date field is

```
    {
      "name": "start_date",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "int",
          "connect.version": 1,
          "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.Date"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
```

It looks like it does not know how to convert an io.debezium.time.Date to a Date and treated it as an int instead.

Any pointers on this are greatly appreciated.

Source Config:

```
{
    "name": "SimpleSQLServerCDC",
    "config":{
      "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
      "tasks.max":1,
      "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
      "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
      "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers":"kafka:29092",
      "database.hostname" : "sqlserver",
      "database.port" : "1433",
      "database.user" : "sa",
      "database.password" : "",
      "database.dbname" : "testDB",
      "database.server.name" : "corporation",

      "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.corporation",
      "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka:29092",

      "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": 1,
      "topic.creation.default.partitions": 10,
      "topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy": "delete"
    }
  }
```

Sink Config:

```
{
  "name": "SimpleMySQLJDBC",
  "config": {
          "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
          "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/sinkdb",
          "connection.user": "user",
          "connection.password": "",
          "tasks.max": "2",
          "topics.regex": "corporation.dbo.*",
          "auto.create": "true",
          "auto.evolve": "true",
          "dialect.name": "MySqlDatabaseDialect",
          "insert.mode": "upsert",
          "pk.mode": "record_key",
          "pk.fields":"id",
          "delete.enabled": "true",
          "batch.size": 1,
          "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
          "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
          "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
          "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",

          "transforms":"unwrap,dropPrefix,insertTS",

          "transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
          "transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"corporation.dbo.(.*)",
          "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"$1",

          "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
          "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones":"false",
          "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode":"drop",

          "transforms.insertTS.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
          "transforms.insertTS.timestamp.field": "messageTS",

          "errors.log.enable": "true",
          "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
          "errors.tolerance":"all",
          "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"dlq-mysql",
          "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true",
          "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor":"1"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> converts VARCHAR(255) to text

The character limit of the fields is not carried through the Connect API datatypes. Any String-like data will become `TEXT` column types.

> DATE to int, and TIME to bigint

I think, by default, datetime values are converted into Unix epoch. You can use the `TimestampConverter` transform to convert to a different format

---

Overall, if you want to accurately preserve types, disable the auto-creation of tables from the sink connector and pre-create tables with the types you want.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried pre-creating all the tables.  It seems that date and time are not handled properly. It gives me error messages like the following: 
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '19055' for column 'start_date' at row 1

Comment: Is that supposed to represent 2019-05-05? Like I said, you'll want to use the TimestampConverter transforms

Answer (score 1):

I just made an SMT that converts all timestamp fields to strings. hopefully, it could help.

https://github.com/FX-HAO/kafka-connect-debezium-tranforms

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 changes
In Source Connector add `"time.precision.mode":"connect"`
In sink connector add

```
"transforms": "TimestampConverter",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "Timestamp",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.field": "dob",
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it automatically for all timestamp fields without specifying each one of them in the sink definition?

Comment: I am not aware of any automation solution and I do not have the setup ready so it is difficult for me to verify but I remember that even if you do not specify other fields then also other timestamp fields are converted automatically.

Comment: @ShantnuJain try this https://github.com/FX-HAO/kafka-connect-debezium-tranforms